# Compare multiple text files, and save commons values

Tags: python

My actual code :

```
import os, os.path

DIR_DAT = "dat"
DIR_OUTPUT = "output"
filenames = []

#in case if output folder doesn't exist
if not os.path.exists(DIR_OUTPUT):
    os.makedirs(DIR_OUTPUT)

#isolating empty values from differents contracts
for roots, dir, files in os.walk(DIR_DAT):  
    for filename in files:
        filenames.append("output/" + os.path.splitext(filename)[0] + ".txt")

        filename_input = DIR_DAT + "/" + filename
        filename_output = DIR_OUTPUT + "/" + os.path.splitext(filename)[0] + ".txt"

        with open(filename_input) as infile, open(filename_output, "w") as outfile:
            for line in infile:
                if not line.strip().split("=")[-1]:
                    outfile.write(line)

#creating a single file from all contracts, nb the values are those that are actually empty
with open(DIR_OUTPUT + "/all_agreements.txt", "w") as outfile:
    for fname in filenames:
        with open(fname) as infile:
            for line in infile:
                outfile.write(line)

#finale file with commons empty data
#creating a single file
with open(DIR_OUTPUT + "/all_agreements.txt") as infile, open(DIR_OUTPUT + "/results.txt", "w") as outfile:
    seen = set()
    for line in infile:
        line_lower = line.lower()
        if line_lower in seen:
            outfile.write(line)
        else:
            seen.add(line_lower)

print("Psst go check in the ouptut folder ;)")
```

The last lines of my code are checking wether or not, element exists mutliple times. So, may the element exists, once, twice, three, four times. It will add it to results.txt.

But the thing is that I want to save it into results.txt only if it exists 4 times in results.txt.

Or best scenario, compare the 4 .txt files and save elements in commons into results.txt.

But I can't solve it..

Thanks for the help :)

---

To make it easier,

```
with open(DIR_OUTPUT + "/all_agreements.txt") as infile, open(DIR_OUTPUT + "/results.txt", "w") as outfile:
    seen = set()
    for line in infile:
        if line in seen:
            outfile.write(line)
        else:
            seen.add(line)
```

Where can I use the .count() function ?
Because I want to do something like xxx.count(line) == 4 then save it into resulsts.txt

Comment: I have trouble understanding what you want. You want to save into `results.txt` the values that exists in 4 other `.txt` files, right ?

Comment: Exact, the commons value from the four others .txt into results.txt. But it is better to do it this way or should I do it earlier in my code ? For instance, creating an array with the four .txt and compare values from there ?

Comment: Could you perhaps show an example input and expected output? I gave an output for writing neat code :).

Comment: STANDARD:sNN0.20=
 INFO_COMP_1:sNN0.32=
 INFO_COMP_2:sNN0.32=
 COMM_TYPE:nNN0.1=

Comment: After each =, it goes to the line. The input and output files looks the same

Answer (score -1):

If your files are not super big you can use `set.intersection(a,b,c,d)`.

```
data = []
for fname in filenames:
    current = set()
    with open(fname) as infile:
        for line in infile:
            current.add(line)
    data.append(current)

results = set.intersection(*data)
```

You also don't need to create one single big file for this issue.

Answer (score -1):

Not sure how your input looks like or what output is expected...

But maybe this can spark some ideas:

```
from io import StringIO
from collections import Counter

lines = ["""\
a=This
b=is
c=a Test
""", """\
a=This
b=is
c=a Demonstration
""", """\
a=This
b=is
c=another
d=example
""", """\
a=This
b=is
c=so much
d=fun
"""]

files = (StringIO(l) for l in lines)

C = Counter(line for f in files for line in f)

print([k for k,v in C.items() if v >= 4])
# Output: ['a=This\n', 'b=is\n']
```